# Create folder in selected folder with OS X Automator

Tags: macos, automator

I am trying to batch convert a bunch of raw image files on OS X. I would like to use built-in software since it is possible.

First I would like to

- let the user select the input folder containing the raw files;
- create a new folder `jpgs` inside of that folder;
- copy the raw files from the user selected folder into `jpgs`.

This is the workflow I have implemented so far in order to implement the first two steps.

[image: Automator Workflow]

First I let the user select a folder and store it into the variable `NEF Folder`. The I create a new folder named `jpgs` in the folder chosen by the user (`NEF Folder`).

BUT this is what the workflow does after selecting folder `AAA` on the Desktop:

[image: Finder output]

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Understood.

The action `New folder` creates a folder and copies its input inside of the newly created folder.

Comment: Just clarifying for others: if you do not wish for the files to be copied as seen in the question, you'll need to check the box "Ignore this action's input" in the `New Folder` options pane

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and solved it checking the box "Ignore this action's input".